# Can the boost::asio timer object be deleted before the corresponding callback is called?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

Should the timer object exist until the task is completed?

I mean the following:

```
boost::asio::io_service io;

{
    boost::asio::steady_timer timer(io, std::chrono::seconds(5));
    timer.async_wait(someCallback);
} // the timer object is deleted here

io.run();
```

Is this allowed and does it lead to undefined behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [destructor](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_waitable_timer/_basic_waitable_timer.html) simply cancels any pending waits so your callback will be called with the [`boost::asio::error::operation_aborted`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_waitable_timer/async_wait.html) error code.